# Create pgp file with gpg from command line

Tags: encryption, gnupg, sign, pgp

I want to encrypt an xml file and I am using gpg4win (kleopatra).
Using the kleopatra interface I set an option to produce files with extension pgp instead of gpg which is the default extension.

I am trying to create a pgp file from command line using the command

```
gpg -r test@test.gr -se C:\temp\myfile.xml
```

because I need to submit it in a web app that accepts pgp only. 
I have tried to put some other options in the command but I always get a gpg file. How can I produce a pgp file from command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may not be the same process as others, but this worked for me:

```
gpg --batch --yes --recipient "user" --output "fulldirectory\filename.txt.pgp" --encrypt "fulldirectory\filename.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

GnuPG syntax for encryption is stated [here](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x110.html). You can simply use the `--output [filename].[suffix]` parameter.

So go with `gpg --encrypt C:\temp\myfile.xml --recipient test@test.gr --output C:\temp\myfile.pgp`.

Please note that .pgp is actually the suffix for a key not an encrypted file. See [here](https://www.filesuffix.com/en/extension/pgp).