# How to encrypt file on disk with ASC public key file using PGP encryption on Windows

Tags: encryption, winscp, pgp

I was told by my client that I need to encrypt a file using PGP with their public ASC key file they sent me. How can I do with WinSCP or another command line utility on Windows Server. I upload via SFTP SSH after I encrypt, but I need to encrypt file before sending to FTP server.

Comment: See [Create pgp file with gpg from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36736086/850848) and many others.

Comment: Correct I looked at those but didn't quite find what I need. I need something like gpg.exe -encrypt -file "somefile.txt" -out "somefile.txt.pgp" -key "c:\mykey.asc"

Comment: I found this so far. but was hoping for something that was shorter code https://blog.bitscry.com/2018/07/05/pgp-encryption-and-decryption-in-c/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Windows, but I just started trying to do this with MacGPG2, and the following seemed to work:

```
gpg --encrypt --recipient-file public-key.asc --output encrypted-file.gpg < plaintext-file.txt
```